# Lucene Search in Sitecore; no results returned

Tags: c#, search, lucene, sitecore, sitecore8

I've got an index that's being generated completely fine (can browse through Luke through all the items created). Did a query in Luke, and even managed to return results back - implemented in the below code in C# but not returns back. Is there anything glaring obvious that I'm missing.

```
            totalResults = 0;
        using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("custom_search_index").CreateSearchContext())
        {
            var filterPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchItem>();
            var termPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<SearchItem>();

            termPredicate = termPredicate
                                .Or(p => p.Name.Like(keyword, 0.75f)).Boost(2.0f)
                                .Or(p => p.Excerpt.Like(keyword))
                                .Or(p => p.SearchTags.Like(keyword))
                                .Or(p => p.HtmlContent.Like(keyword));

            var predicate = filterPredicate.And(termPredicate);
            var query = context.GetQueryable<SearchItem>().Where(predicate);

            var results = query.Page(page, itemsPerPage).GetResults();

            totalResults = results.TotalSearchResults;
            var result = results.Hits.Select(h => GetPage(h.Document)).ToArray();

            return result;
        }
```

in Search.Log i'm getting the following hit

> ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (custom_search_index): _name:1980s~0.75 excerpt:1980s searchtags:1980s htmlcontent:1980s - Filter :

If i run '_name:1980s~0.75 excerpt:1980s searchtags:1980s htmlcontent:1980s' in Luke I do get a result back!

Comment: Just to be sure, are you using Luke on the same custom index, i.e. `custom_search_index`? Is `totalResults` also 0 and what does the `GetPage()` function return?

Comment: yes using the same index in both instances. GetPage() maps the item to Sitecore items for more details.

Comment: Is the problem only with '1980s'? Have you tried with letters-only query?

Comment: yes, if i removed the where clause in the query, i do get all the pages! So the problem seems to be in regards to the filtering part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if i use the following code:

```
var results = query.Page(page, itemsPerPage).GetResults();
```

where page is 1 and itemsPerPage is 5, but my filtered results returns only one value (or less then itemsPerPage) GetResults() returns no results!

Comment: Yes, the `page` value is zero-based. The code for the `Page(..)` extension method is this: `Queryable.Take<TSource>(Queryable.Skip<TSource>(source, page * pageSize), pageSize)` so it will first `Skip` 1 * 5 and then `Take` 5 items.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, this indicates that the index is out-of-date. For instance, the items the results point to have been deleted or haven't been published yet. Rebuilding the index should result in having Luke and Sitecore return the same.

Also, check if your paging doesn't exclude results. Maybe try it first without paging.

Comment: if i removed the where clause in the query, i do get all the pages! so the problem seems to be in regards to the filtering part.

Comment: Or in the paging part, because with no filtering you might get plenty of results satisfying your paging arguments.

Comment: that is weird, if i filter and exclude the pager it returns the one match (as it should)! why would the pager return nothing if there's one result?

Answer (score 1):

From the other comments it seems like you are using `page = 1` to get the first page of results.

But the `page` parameter is zero-based, meaning if you want the first page you have to use 0.

```
// This will return the first 5 results (page 1)
query.Page(0, 5).GetResults();

// This will return the next 5 results (page 2)
query.Page(1, 5).GetResults();
```

This can be verified by looking at the code for the `Page(..)` extension method:

```
return Queryable.Take<TSource>(Queryable.Skip<TSource>(source, page * pageSize), pageSize);
```

Comment: thanks, yeah afterwords realized that it's zero based!